# TCL SQLITE query return for text fields with spaces (list vs. non-list)

Tags: sqlite, tcl

When performing a tcl sqlite extension query where there is a single result that is a string with spaces, the return value can either be a string or a list depending on how the query is evaluated.  Why is there a distinction and what should be the expected behavior?

Example of TCL session with sqlite extension:

```tcl
package require sqlite3

sqlite3 db :memory:

db eval {select 'space separated string'}
```

results in a list:

```
{space separated string}
```

however, using onecolumn, it returns a string value

```tcl
db onecolumn {select 'space separated string'}
```

result

```
space separated string
```

Why does the sqlite eval return a list and onecolumn return a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined to work that way. The [documentation](https://sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html#onecolumn) says:

> ## The "onecolumn" method
>
> The "onecolumn" method works like "[eval](https://sqlite.org/tclsqlite.html#eval)" in that it evaluates the SQL query statement given as its argument. The difference is that "onecolumn" returns a single element which is the first column of the first row of the query result.
>
> This is a convenience method. It saves the user from having to do a "`[lindex ... 0]`" on the results of an "eval" in order to extract a single column result.

That is, a `onecolumn` method returns just the *first* column of the *first* row of the result set (or a boolean when no result is produced). When you're writing a query that produces only one row and only one column in that row, it retrieves that value and so is very convenient for the "evaluate an expression" scenario. The value it retrieves is always a simple value in an SQL sense; your simple value happens to include spaces so naturally they're in the result of `onecolumn`.